# Visual Studio Python Shell

Tags: python, visual-studio, shell, interactive

Quick question. I'm scratching my head as to why the latest version of visual studio offers tabs with interactive python terminals. As well as debugging terminals all built into the tabs that can be snapped. But when I attach & test run something it just opens a normal python terminal in CMD rendering the built terminals in VS useless. I'm just thinking why lol. They never get used. Is there a way to test run script in the built-in interactive terminals instead of it opening a Python shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about this feature [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/interactive-repl), it's just another repl with the convenience of being within Visual Studio. There's also some interesting connections to the editor that you can send selected code lines to the interactive window. I'm not sure how variable scoping works between the two but sometimes you just want to experiment in the repl before integrating it into a working python file.

I mostly put the `Immediate Window` to use for some interactive exploratory coding when I develop in Visual Studio. This is scoped to where the current breakpoint is set which is good for manipulating things on the fly and getting feedback about my variables and what not.